# Child CSS not working for some of the classes - twenty seventeen theme

Tags: theme-twenty-seventeen

Parent and child CSS both classes loading as per CSS rules, but parent is functioning and child failing.

```
.navigation-top {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation-top {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e60909;
}
```

My `functions.php` is shown below:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove that closing `?>` PHP tag from your `functions.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should type with

```
!important;
```

Tag with css like these it will work

```
.navigation-top { background-color: #eeeeee !important; border-bottom: 2px solid #e60909 !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked... You saved my time .. :)

Comment: my pleasures please click on "accept Answer" if it helpful for you :-)